# Read in and append sheets by column in Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I am trying to read in my workbook and append certain worksheets in order to create 1 big table. However, I only want to append according to certain columns (f_name, lname, address ect)

> I keep getting an error that says     with
>   pd.read_excel(xls,sheet,lines = True) as df: AttributeError: **exit**

I am not sure what the issue is.

```
import sys, os
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import xlwt


b = ['sh1', 'sh2','sh3'] #sheet Name
df_t = pd.DataFrame(columns=["fname","lname","address","zip","school"])
xls= 'address/Documents/wrkbook.xls'
for sheet in b:
       with pd.read_excel(xls,sheet,lines = True) as df:
              df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip().upper(), inplace=True)
              df_b = df_b.append(df[columns])
              Surveys = df_b

Survey.to_excel('Surveyss.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) check whether the xls address needs to be a raw string say if it has spaces in it etc e.g. r'address here/workbook.xls'

2) check your sheet exists and then parse as `sheet_name=sheet`

3) not sure whether there is such thing as `lines` parameter now. Check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_excel.html